# using Pearson's r test to return correlation score and p-value of two sets of variables

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment in basic python class and I am stumped...  can anyone help me calculate the Pearson's r test returning the correlation score and the p-value for two sets of variables. You'll use a preloaded DataFrame that contains information about medical costs in different regions of the country and across other demographics, including age, sex, BMI (body mass index), number of children, and smoker versus nonsmoker.

For this challenge, you'll focus on the correlations between age and charges, and bmi and charges.

Before you get started, you'll be introduced to a new Python concept to help you in this task: assigning values to multiple variables at once.

In Python, it's possible (and often very convenient) to assign values to multiple variables at once (on the same line of code).

Consider the following code:

a, b = 5, 10
print(a)
print(b)
The above is equivalent to this code:

a = 5
b = 10
print(a)
print(b)
The pearsonr method that you'll be using returns two values at once, so you'll need to assign them to two variables at once, just like in the code above.

For the correlation between age and charges, assign the test value to the variable ac and the p-value to ap. Print out both results.

For the correlation between bmi and charges, assign the test value to the variable bc and the p-value to bp. Print out both results.

You'll notice that they both have significant p-values (less than 0.05). However, your results should show that age is more highly correlated with charges than bmi is. Interesting!

CODE

## Import libraries

import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

## Load DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/data-analytics-bootcamp/medicalcosts.csv')

## Use the 'pearsonr' correlation test to check for correlation between `age` and `charges` and print the results

ac, ap = stats.*****(*****, *****)
print(*****)

## Use the 'pearsonr' correlation test to check for correlation between `bmi` and `charges` and print the results

bc, bp = stats.*****(*****, *****)
print(*****)

Answer (score 1):

The below is what you need to get the results requested in the instructions (ps. make sure you have [scipy](https://scipy.org/install/) installed):

```
import pandas as pd 
from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv('https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/data-analytics-bootcamp/medicalcosts.csv')

ac, ap = stats.pearsonr(df.age, df.charges) 
print(ac) 
print(ap)

bc, bp = stats.pearsonr(df.bmi, df.charges) 
print(bc)
print(bp)
```

A good approach at solving this by yourself is to search for the documentation of the library you are using and find the function needed, so that you can get a better idea of how to use it.

The statistical function [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) has two required parameters x and y, and it returns a [PearsonRResult](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats._result_classes.PearsonRResult.html#scipy.stats._result_classes.PearsonRResult). From that documentation, you can see that in addition to the r statistic and the p-value, you can also calculate a confidence interval at different confidence levels (using the function confidence_interval() which by defaults calculate an interval using a 0.95 confidence_level).

If you would have assigned the result of the function to just one varible, that variable would have been of the type PearsonRResult and you could have access its attributes with dot notation:

```
age_pearson_r_test = stats.pearsonr(df.age, df.charges) 

print(age_pearson_r_test.statistic)
print(age_pearson_r_test.pvalue)
print(age_pearson_r_test.confidence_interval())
print(age_pearson_r_test.confidence_interval(confidence_level=0.99))
```

Which outputs:

```
0.29900813459514475
4.886820193672555e-29
ConfidenceInterval(low=0.24941385646250505, high=0.3470380706330515)
ConfidenceInterval(low=0.23354154009423367, high=0.36177608359744545)
```

If you were confused about assigning two variables to the result of a function, a similar example can help you get a better sense of what is going on:

```
def test_function():
    return 1,2

tuple_result = test_function()

int_result_1, int_result_2 = test_function()

print(type(tuple_result))
print(tuple_result)

print(type(int_result_1))
print(int_result_1)

print(type(int_result_2))
print(int_result_2)
```

Which outputs:

```
<class 'tuple'>
(1, 2)
<class 'int'>
1
<class 'int'>
2
```

Comment: Isaac- thank you so much for explaining this to me in such great detail. I learned more from your reply than the month I have been studying Python!

Comment: I am happy to have helped!

Comment: Also, if you could please help me by accepting/approving my answer (clicking the check mark next to my answer), I would appreciate it. Thank you!